# When does it make sense to use ADF?

Tags: node.js, oracle-adf

I'm in a company re-writing the existing applications, using the full Oracle stack, in a SOA way.

Everything is nice and so on until we're starting to discuss the UI. We are wondering what to use as web framework in order to web application.

In the first hand, we are developers in love with NodeJS and frameworks like Ember.js, we're developing today (until the application is migrated) in Ruby on Rails (so working with Macs). In the other hand, Oracle is providing ADF which is obviously well integrated in the Oracle stack and so on. But when we compare ADF to the way we are working today (Ruby on Rails) or the way we would work in the future (with Ember.js for instance) it looks like less development, more point and click, with an heavy framework.

- What are the advantages of ADF ?
- What are the right domains where ADF make sense ?
- How popular is ADF ? (Especially in the enterprise context)
- How hard is the learning of ADF for someone developing today with Ruby On Rails (IDE is Sublime Text, so all is about writing code -- mouse not needed) while for ADF JDeveloper seems mandatory (seems a large use of the mouse and less writing code ?)

I hope my post is understandable.

Comment: If you like Eclipse, the Oracle tools for Eclipse include ADF support, you don't have to use JDeveloper.

Comment: That's just marketing  @James_Parsons. ADF was designed to work the best with ADF Faces  and ADF Business Components - developed with Jdeveloper. Anything else is both less productive and less stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used in production java frameworks like Struts, Struts2, JBoss Seam, Tapestry, Spring, Hibernate and I've moved to ADF 6 years ago, therefore I can't comment on how ADF compares with NodeJS or Ember.js.

> What are the advantages of ADF ?

ADF has in Jdeveloper a strong development tool support. If your team is not technically very strong in Java, it might be the right tool for you.

> What are the right domains where ADF make sense ?

Web applications providing Desktop-like experience: that means complex input forms, complex querying - screens with lots of data and business rules. By far the most productive framework I've used when building these kind of web applications.

> How popular is ADF ? (Especially in the enterprise context)

ADF is a niche at the moment. Though it is strongly supported by Oracle. Most of Oracle's products - e.g. Fusion Apps - are based on ADF, so ADF is here to stay.

> How hard is the learning of ADF for someone developing today with Ruby
>   On Rails (IDE is Sublime Text, so all is about writing code -- mouse
>   not needed) while for ADF JDeveloper seems mandatory (seems a large
>   use of the mouse and less writing code ?)

At start, it will look like you are having good progress in relatively short period of time. Then, you will realise that even though Jdeveloper does 'everything' for you, you need to  understand every piece of code JDeveloper generates. ADF has a steep learning curve (though you may find  others telling you otherwise), it requires a different way of thinking web application development, especially difficult for developers with previous web experience: ADF is using a STATEFUL business layer. So, unless you have been using Stateful Session Beans before, there are good chances to mess up your first ADF Design - is what I keep seeing as ADF consultant. But once you've learn it, productivity-wise is fantastic.

From innovation point of view, ADF sounds like listening to Vanilla Ice in your Beats headsets:  it is based on XML, it uses JSF, no sign of dependency injection  on ADF Faces. Still, is Ajax-based.

Comment: Are you saying that ADF is better for non-developers. Would a (somewhat) experienced developer be better off using Spring or just plain Java EE?

Comment: ADF 11g was targeted for people with previous Oracle Forms experience. These people had little or no experience with Java, but they understand SQL beyond the level an average Java EE developer would. So Oracle came up with this solution- XML based framework, minimising java code writing. Their success greatly depends on IDE quality: there is a lot of click and drag and drop going on.  In my opinion- Oracle nailed it : people without a basic Java EE experience are writing Java EE applications. Is what I previously meant by "ignorant"- knowing a framework, not knowing the technologies underneath

Comment: Difficult question for me to answer:"Experienced developer be better off using Spring or just plain Java EE", since I have no practical experience with Java EE frameworks popular after 2007. But I can say that up until that moment there was no java framework (or combination of frameworks) I was aware of to allow building complex input data screens so easily as ADF does. I still remember ridiculous problems we've used to have when using Spring/Hibernate/OpenSessionInView back then, when wizard like input data screens.